# Windows 8 can't log in once the pc is locked

Tags: windows-8, login-screen

When I lock my PC and walk away, if I leave it long enough, I can no longer log in.

When I get back, I move my mouse and it takes at least 30 seconds to turn the screens back on.

However, when I click on the screen, or I press any key on the keyboard, I can no longer log in.  The password entry screen does not appear.

The mouse tracks normally across the screen, but I can't get the login screen to appear.

I have disabled the setting 'USB selective suspend setting' in the power options but this did not fix the issue.

Any thoughts?

**edit**

I don't know whether the keyboard is functional at this point or not.  It responds to Num Lock and Caps Lock by turning on the lights on the keyboard, but no matter what I type, I cannot get the login screen to appear.

Not even repeatably hitting Ctrl-Alt-Del helps.

The only way to log back in is to turn the computer off and then on again using the power button.

**edit**

I just noticed that the clock, which appears on the screen directly before the login screen, had stopped at a certain time.  My assumption here is that is stopped at the time that Windows hung.

Corrupted installation?  Was working fine until yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

The LEDs are an internal fct of the kbd and not an indication that the computer is seeing the kbd.
I assume there is some period of time when it will come back to life.
look at your pwr options and see if u can relate that time to one of the settings.
that may give u a clue as to what is happening.
chk ur event viewer to see if there is anything there that might help.

Comment: I have tried to unplug and plug in the keyboard.  I have moved the keyboard to another port.
I think it might be after 5 minutes which relates to no timeout i can see.
The event view does not seem to contain any errors that are even remotely close to this.
I did notice that the clock has stopped on the screen that appears directly ahead of the login screen.  So it looks as though windows hangs.